# how to select next elemt in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a html like below, Problem is that i want to find/select next div after this image and toggle its visibilty

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="src" class="minmax" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="minmaxdiv">
    div contents
</div>


<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="src" class="minmax" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="minmaxdiv">
    div contents
</div>
```

each image have `class="minmax"` after its click must toggle the visibility of first div after itself.

first img tag must toggle the first div & the second must toggle the second tag.

for example i have tried `$(".minmax:first").parents("table:first").nextUntil("div.minmaxdiv")` but the result is empty jquery object

Comment: 'nextUntil' will "get all following siblings of each element up to *but not including* the element matched by the selector" -- which means nothing, in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".minmax").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("table").next(".minmaxdiv").toggle()
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cxeXP/)

Comment: i also checked this, result is empty: `$(".minmax:eq(0)").closest("table").next(".minmaxdiv")`

Answer (score 2):

While perhaps not the most elegant solution, you should be able to do this:

```
$('.minmax').click(function()
{
    var index = $('.minmax').index(this);
    $('.minmaxdiv').eq(index).toggle();
});
```

Comment: o_O: Working, thanks, but what is problem with `next, nextAll, nextUntil` & Other functions? all return jquery empty object

Comment: I'm thinking the algorithm behind `closest` simply can't find a good match.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".minmax").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('table').next('.minmaxdiv').toggle();

});
```

OR

```
$(".minmax").click(function() {
     $(this).closest('table').nextAll('.minmaxdiv').first().toggle();

 });
```

[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/7YkdS/)

Comment: checked, can not find the div